# How to Enable/Disable checkbox in dataTable based on the value of column in the row

Tags: checkbox, primefaces, datatable

I need your help in enabling/disabling the checkbox in the dataTable based on the column remarks in the dataTable. If the remarks column is not empty or blank, then the checkbox of the row should be disabled, otherwise it should be enabled if the remarks column is empty or blank.

I need to do it from the backing bean in the method. The dataTable code is:

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{testController.employeeList}" id="Employee" var="emp" 
rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
    selection="#{testController.selectedEmployees}" rowKey="#{emp.id}" 
rowSelectMode="checkbox">
                        <p:columnGroup type="header">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column/>
                            <p:column headerText="ID"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Name"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Remarks"/>
                            <p:column headerText="Update"/>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:columnGroup>
                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
                    <p:column headerText="ID">
                        <h:outputText value="#{emp.id}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Name">
                        <h:outputText value="#{emp.name}" id="name"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Remarks">
                        <h:inputText id="inputT1" value="#{emp.remarks}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Update">
                        <p:commandButton id="updateCmd" title="Update"
                                         actionListener="#{testController.updateRecord}">
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

In the init method:

```
public void init() {
if (e.getRemarks.equals("") || e.getRemarks == null)
{
// I need to update the checkbox to be enabled
}
else
{
//I need to update the checkbox to be disabled
}
```

Comment: Use disabledSelection="#{ not empty emp.remarks}" on datatable

Comment: @Unknown Thanks for the response. This will solve part of the problem while loading the dataTable on the page load.  The other problem is when I call the UpdateRecord method after clicking on the commandButton, I should be able to enable the checkbox, so how can I do that?

Comment: What is your use case? Are you okay to update whole data table instead of cell?

Comment: I need only to update the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update only the checkbox you need to add 2 property in your Employee class

```
private Boolean selected;
private Boolean isRemarkNotEmpty;
```

and assign `isRemarkNotEmpty = (remarks!=null)&&(!remarks.trim().isEmpty())` while creating the object.

Data table:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{testController.employeeList}" id="Employee"
                    var="emp" widgetVar="employeeTable" rowIndexVar="row"
                        rowKey="#{emp.id}">

                    <p:columnGroup type="header">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column/>
                        <p:column headerText="ID"/>
                        <p:column headerText="Name"/>
                        <p:column headerText="Remarks"/>
                        <p:column headerText="Update"/>
                    </p:row>
                </p:columnGroup>
                <p:column>
                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{emp.selected}" disabled="#{emp.isRemarkNotEmpty}" id="myCheckBox"></p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="ID">
                    <h:outputText value="#{emp.id}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{emp.name}" id="name"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Remarks">
                    <h:inputText id="inputT1" value="#{emp.remarks}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Update">
                    <p:commandButton id="updateCmd" title="Update"
                                     actionListener="#{testController.updateRecord}">
                            <f:attribute name="rowId" value="#{row}"></f:attribute>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

Update method:

```
public void updateRecord(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Integer rowId = (Integer)actionEvent.getComponent().getAttributes().get("rowId");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Employee selectedRecord = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{emp}", Employee.class);
        selectedRecord.setIsRemarkNotEmpty(false);
 RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("myform:sEmployee:"+rowId+":myCheckBox");
    }
```